# Bug in SubSonic.Comparison.In

Tags: subsonic, comparison

With the following code:

```
 IEnumerable<int> LocalityIds = new List<int>();

        PersonCollection pc = 
            new PersonCollection().
                Where(Person.Columns.AddressLocalityId, SubSonic.Comparison.In, LocalityIds).
                Load();
```

Although the initial collection is empty Subsonic still returns all records?!?!?!?!? Is this a bug or am i doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: In my code, I have to manually check the list before using an IN to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we've setup collections to do this even though the Comparison is there. Have you tried Select().From().Where(..).In(LocalityIds).ExecuteAsCollection();

Comment: so can we Load the return of that into a PersonCollection object?

Comment: Also..it does work fine if initial collection is not empty...that's why I assume that it is a bug...

Thanks for helping out

Luis

Comment: Hey Rob sorry for bugging you, where can I report this, or better yet can I get this fixed and submit it to your source control? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just checked V2.2 and this still happens, when I have a bit of time I will try to submit a patch